# Trigger a Travis-CI rebuild without pushing a commit?

Tags: travis-ci

Using Travis-CI, is it possible to trigger a rebuild without pushing a new commit to GitHub?

Use case: A build fails due to an externality. The source is actually correct. It would build OK and pass if simply re-run.

For instance, an `apt-get` fails due to a package server being down, but the server is back up again. However the build status is "stuck" at "failed" until a new commit is pushed.

Is there some way to nudge Travis-CI to do another build, other than pushing a "dummy" commit?

Answer (score 477, accepted):

- **If you have write access to the repo**: On the build's detail screen, there is a button **↻ Restart Build**. Also under "More Options" there is a trigger build menu item.

  *Note*: Browser extensions like Ghostery may prevent the restart button from being displayed. Try disabling the extension or white-listing Travis CI.

  *Note2*: If `.travis.yml` configuration has changed in the upstream, clicking rebuild button will run travis with old configuration. To apply upstream changes for travis configuration one has to add commit to PR or to close / reopen it.
- **If you've sent a pull request**: You can [close the PR then open it again](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/576#issuecomment-65317915). This will trigger a new build.

**Restart Build:**

[image: Restart Build Screen Shot]

**Trigger Build:**

[image: Trigger Build Screen Shot]

Comment: I have found and used that in other cases. But I could have sworn I had a case where it had Errored for the reason I described above, and the gear menu lacked that option. Perhaps that was a one-time fluke, or perhaps I was mistaken. Anyway, I think you answered how it's _supposed_ to work, so I'll go ahead and mark your answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I can't find that option as well. Is there another way?

Comment: If I look at the build history of any of the projects I own, errored or failed, it has a [restart button](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14785065/Img/travis-ci.jpg)

Comment: I think one tricky case is where you submit a pull request for someone else's project, and it errored for reasons unrelated to your PR per se, and you _know_ it would succeed if you could just nudge it to try again. It's understandable why you can't (not your project) -- but also understandable why you'd want to (your PR incorrectly "looks bad").

Comment: Don't forget you have to be signed in to see this :P

Comment: And you need to have write access to the github repro. So this won't work for forks pushed upstream.

Comment: Plus you actually have to _have_ a build to press the restart button on.

Comment: What can you do if the build was never triggered in the first place *and* there isn't a Pull Request open? (ie. it's just a commit on a branch, maybe even on `master`)

Comment: What do you do if the button is there, you click it, and it says the job was successfully restarted, but there is no other indication that it did?

Comment: NOTE: This will NOT reconfigure the build, so if there has been a fix on upstream to the build process itself (such as chaning `before_install` in `.travis.yml`), this will NOT be applied by clicking that button: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6031#issuecomment-218139497

Comment: @Gerry Has point there, pushing rebuild button doesn't account changes in `.travis.yml` etc. In that case one has to add new commit or close / reopen the pull request.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that it replaces the existing build with the new build. If what you want is to trigger a new build (perhaps to demonstrate something that's changed environmentally between that build and now), the Restart Build button is not what you want.

Comment: `git ci --amend --no-edit && git push origin [your-branch] --force` will trigger a Travis CI rebuild. But be caution since this will override the previous commit.

Comment: I don't find this button. Has it been removed?

Comment: @uri it needs a new screen shot but it’s still there when you are logged in under the “more options” drop down

Comment: @jbtule It's not there at all.

Comment: Updated screen shots.

Comment: @uri “my repositories” is blank so I think that is where your problem is, it doesn’t see you as having any ownership on the repo.

Comment: @jbtule there was a problem with cookies with Travis CI - after I logged out and logged in again, this button exists. I think they have a separate cookie for repositories, separate from the login cookies.

Answer (score 208):

If you open the **Settings** tab for the repository on GitHub, click on **Integrations & services**, find **Travis CI** and click **Edit**, you should see a **Test Service** button.  This will trigger a build.

Comment: I think travis-ci removed the restart build button, so this is the only way that worked for me right. It performs *two* builds though…

Comment: @Blaise by any chance do you use Ghostery (or similar)? Try disabling that. For me, this cause the Restart Build button to reappear.

Comment: This works when you initially activate the Travis CI building for a repo. The "reload build" button doesn't exist for a repo that doesn't have any previous builds.

Comment: A note for idiots like me: Open `Settings` in the repository _on Github_, not on Travis's repo page! I can't believe I wasted 20 mins trying to find `Service Hooks` on Travis's page. :(

Comment: Cannot see this option in github.

Answer (score 91):

I know you said without pushing a commit, but something that is handy, if you are working on a branch other than master, is to commit an empty commit.

`git commit --allow-empty -m "Trigger"`

You can rebase in the end and remove squash/remove the empty commits and works across all git hooks :)

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you! I just want to add that I had to rebase in order to move the "Trigger" commit further down in history; otherwise it would simply discard the new build upon removal of the "Trigger" commit.

Comment: in the same vein, you can amend the existing commit and force push: git commit --amend --no-edit && git push -f

Comment: @grahamrhay that's the best to trigger a PR build when you're not the owner of the target repo, it keeps the contents, no need to merge or rebase or do anything. Please make it an answer so it's possible to upvote it more visibly.

Comment: I forked a repository I didn't have access to, and this was the only thing that worked for me because Travis didn't have any builds I could restart on my newly created fork.

Comment: @TWiStErRob Someone else wrote such an answer below.

Answer (score 37):

I have found another way of forcing re-run CI builds and other triggers:

1. Run `git commit --amend --no-edit` without any changes. This will recreate the last commit in the current branch.
2. `git push --force-with-lease origin pr-branch`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. It destructively modifies the history so it might confuse people that have branches based off of this commit, and the `--amend` flag also might not change the `HEAD` commit in some cases.

Comment: I find it fine for the rare occasions when you need only BUMP webhooks for a PR. Nobody should really branch out of pull-requests, so nobody will rely on the exact commit id.

Comment: go for `git push --force-with-lease origin pr-branch` so you don't accidentally nuke someone else's changes

Answer (score 20):

If you have new project on GitHub which has .travis.yml, but was never tested, you can run tests without commit this way:

1. enable testing in Travis CI setings
2. open project page on GitHub
3. open settings -> webhooks and services
4. find Travis CI in services and press edit button [image]
5. press "Test service" [image]

Comment: This is the answer for those with newly created projects.

Answer (score 16):

You can do this using the [Travis CLI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb). As [described in the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds), first install the CLI tool, then:

```
travis login --org --auto
travis token
```

You can keep this token in an environment variable `TRAVIS_TOKEN`, as long as the file you keep it in is not version-controlled somewhere public.

I use this function to submit triggers:

```
function travis_trigger() {
     local org=$1 && shift
     local repo=$1 && shift
     local branch=${1:-master} && shift

     body="{
             \"request\": {
               \"branch\": \"${branch}\"
              }
           }"

     curl -s -X POST \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
          -H "Accept: application/json" \
          -H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
          -H "Authorization: token $TRAVIS_TOKEN" \
          -d "$body" \
          "https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/${org}%2F${repo}/requests"
 }
```

Comment: You can setup your own Travis build for your fork.

Comment: You can build the branch of your fork that the pull request is made from.

Comment: The branch of your PR and the PR are essentially the same thing, right? If upstream has other changes since you made the PR, sure, you need to rebase it to be 100% sure. But that would need to happen anyway, and GitHub should show a rebase button in the UI which would trigger a new build of the PR in that case.

Comment: what is type or extension of this file

Answer (score 12):

Travis now offers a way to trigger a "custom" build from their web UI.  Look for the "More Options" menu button on the right side near the top of your project's page.

[image: More Options → Trigger Build]

You'll then be presented with a dialog box in which you can choose the branch and customize the configuration:

[image: Custom Build Dialog Box]

At the time I'm writing this it is in beta, and appears to be slightly buggy (but I expect they'll get the problems ironed out soon).

Comment: Thanks. For me, it's the best response because a trigger build changes also build's ID, not with a simple rebuild (via the button). If you use Travis' id in your scripts, it's important to know.

Comment: This needs to be higher up

Answer (score 8):

If you install the [Travis CI Client](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#installation) you can use `travis restart <job#>` to manually re-run a build from the console. You can find the last job# for a branch using `travis show <branch>`

```
travis show master
travis restart 48 #use Job number without .1
travis logs master
```

[image: Travis CI Client]

**UPDATE:** Sadly it looks like this doesn't start a new build using the latest commit, but instead just restarts a previous build using the previous state of the repo.

Comment: I do not understand the update note. From the command it seems like you can define what job to restart. So the question is about to trigger a job, presumingly most people would want to do this if their commit already triggered but they want to test it again to so ... Oh I guess you cant deactivate commit branch triggers and manually build HEAD.

Comment: @redanimalwar a common use-case is forcing a CI build when it fails to detect changes or is in a quiet period.

Answer (score 4):

If the build never occurred (perhaps you didn't get the Pull-Request build switch set to on in time), you can mark the Pull Request on Github as closed then mark it as opened and a new build will be triggered.

Answer (score 4):

I should mention here that we now have a means of triggering a new build on the web. See https://blog.travis-ci.com/2017-08-24-trigger-custom-build for details.

TL;DR
Click on "More options", and choose "Trigger build".

Comment: This doesn't work if you have no write access/colaborator to the repository and want to rerun build for your own pull request. I don't see that option. And when trying the Travis CLI, it says `build #xxxx has been restarted`  but if you look in the webpage you don't see any build happening

Answer (score 1):

I just triggered the tests on a pull request to be re-run by clicking 'update branch' here:
[image: github check tests component]

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me to trigger a rebuild on a PR that Dependabot had opened, but failed due to errors in `.travis.yml`:

1. Close the PR
2. Wait for Dependabot to comment ("OK, I won't notify you again about this release, but will get in touch when a new version is available."). It will remove its branch.
3. Restore the branch Dependabot removed (something like `dependabot/cargo/tempfile-3.0.4`).
4. Open the PR again

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to **Log In** to Travis first. The rebuild button doesn't appear until you're logged in. I know this is obvious, but someone just tripped on it as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it happens that server do made some mistakes. 
try log out/sign in and everything might be right then.
(Yes it happened this afternoon to me.)

Answer (score -1):

Simlpy close and re-open the PR if you do not have the write access.

Comment: No, PLEASE don't leave garbage pull requests, it's annoying. Just push new commit(s) to your branch (for example you can change the commit date: git commit --amend --date=now && git push -f).