# Travis CI build when repository is first added

Tags: github, travis-ci

Is it possible to trigger a build when a forked repository is first added to Travis CI? I just forked it and want to test the build before I start modifying the code. I know I can restart an existing build as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606874/trigger-a-travis-ci-rebuild-without-pushing-a-commit), but when a repository is first added there are no builds to restart. I also looked in Settings but could not find anything that would let me trigger a build.

Edit: I also tried going to my GitHub repo -> Settings -> WebHooks & Services -> Travis CI
When I clicked "Test Service" I received the following error: "Oops, we weren't able to send the test payload: no pushes found."

Comment: Did you push at least one new commit since the fork took place?

Comment: No, I have not pushed any commits. My question is if you can verify that the build is working before making any changes.

Comment: Then maybe adding an empty commit (http://stackoverflow.com/q/20138640/6309) just for testing could be a way to find out. It is your fork: you can remove that commit after the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding [an empty commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20138640/55075) just for testing could be a way to find out.

It is your fork: you can remove that commit after the test.

Comment: This does seem to be the only option. Would be nice if travis allowed you to trigger a build, like circleci.