# check status of job requested through travis API v3

Tags: api, travis-ci

So I've submitted a request using [travis api v3 guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/#Customizing-the-build-configuration) and got response like:

```
{
  "@type": "pending",
  "remaining_requests": 10,
  "repository": {
    "@type": "repository",
    "@href": "/repo/111111111",
    "@representation": "minimal",
    "id": 111111111,
    "name": "my-111111111",
    "slug": "me/my111111111"
  },
  "request": {
    "repository": {
      "id": 222222,
      "owner_name": "me",
      "name": "my-111111111"
    },
    "user": {
      "id": 333333
    },
    "id": 444444,
    "message": "Cool message",
    "branch": "master"
  },
  "resource_type": "request"
}
```

So what is the way to get status of those jobs now? I suppose that I need to use id 444444, but I am getting error below, not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
curl -s -X POST \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -H "Accept: application/json" \
 -H "Travis-API-Version: 3" \
 -H "Authorization: token mycooltoken" \
 https://api.travis-ci.org/repo/111111111/requests/444444


{
  "@type": "error",
  "error_type": "not_found",
  "error_message": "resource not found (or insufficient access)"
}
```

Can somebody point me where to look for examples or any other idea?

Comment: Maybe shoot an email to support@travis-ci.com including all the details (except the token) that you have masqueraded now.

Answer (score 2):

Oh sorry for confusion - somehow I overlooked that I must change POST to GET; with that simple fix everything worked fine.