# Trigger a job from command line

Tags: travis-ci-cli

How to trigger a job on-demand on a disabled repo ?

The doc is not clear about that,https://docs.travis-ci.com/api

There are apis to  restart `jobs`/`builds`, but not to start.

I can't find api to enable / disable repository.

Comment: Does this cover it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40223297/2492

Comment: idk https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#requests

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The linked answer allows you to trigger a build from the command line. The travis client allows you to enable/disable projects. Did you try it?